# How response from http.request works under the hood with two writable streams?

Tags: node.js, streaming

Basically, I have a response coming from http.request. I have to write to 2 writable streams and I have some questions about it:

When I am doing

```
response.pipe(writable1); // Will write very fast
response.pipe(writable2); // Will write slowly
```

- Am I sending two gets to response's source (Using double bandwidth)?
- Can this code have some memory issues? If so, where exactly?
- One thing there is not clear to me, do I have to manually close the response or can I trust that nodejs will close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. No, there is only only one copy of the data coming from `response`. The data will only go as fast as the slowest stream that `response` is piped to, as can be seen in the [code for writing to piped streams](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/523929c9272a53c9429616564a45f2af59670e47/lib/_stream_readable.js#L601-L620) shows.
2. No, streaming only buffers so much in memory until backpressure kicks in. When the writable streams can't handle any more data for the moment, `write()` will return false, causing `response` to stop reading data from the socket until whichever writable stream has its internal buffer drained.
3. You don't manually close the response. It will eventually have no more data available and will end at that time, closing any streams it has been piped to.

Comment: About 3, What happens if a user is downloading a file from my site(wriatable2) and he closes the download. The code will keep downloading from the remote location(response) until the response is finished or it will also close/destroy/(send close event) the response. Let's say that we don't have writable1 here because of course it will continue the download.